# Why code coverage is different when measured by eCobertura and EclEmma?

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura, eclemma

When using eCobertura and EclEmma resp. I found the code coverage come out as different in each case for the *same* project.
Interested to know why?

Emma stat
[image: EclEmma stat]

[image: eCobertura stat]

eCobertura stat

Comment: As far as i see eCobertura got statistics not from all application. Are you sure that you run eCobertura on all package, not only on one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One factor may be that EclEmma [does not measure coverage correctly for exception handling code](http://www.eclemma.org/faq.html#trouble02) - i.e. it may tell you that code is not covered, when in fact it is executed (e.g. if you step through with the debugger, the code is indeed executed). This is a limitation of the underlying JaCoCo library. No idea whether eCobertura has the same issue though.

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot you have attached you configure EclEmma to show you the 'instruction counters' but eCobertura shows you lines and branches counters. You [can configure EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/coverageview.html) to show you 'branches counters' and 'line counters'.